# Projection map of the Hirzebruch surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider the Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{F}_0:=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})\xrightarrow{\pi}\mathbb{P}^1$. We know that
$$\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}_0}(n)\cong\mathsf{Sym}^n(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})$$
and in particular $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}_0}\cong\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$. In this case one has
$$\pi_*\pi^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n))\cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n)$$
by projection formula. I wonder what is precisely the $\pi^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n)$.

Comment: If $f$ is the fibre of $\pi$, then $\pi^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n)$  is the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}_0}(nf)$. The corresponding linear system is $|nf|$, whose general element is the union of $n$ fibres.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_0= \mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ and $\pi$ is just one of the obvious projections, so $\pi^*$ should be easy to understand.